# Why does Infant Jesus wear a big crown in pictures?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, art

In many images of Infant Jesus, (for example Infant Jesus of Prague,) he is shown as wearing a huge crown which looks larger-than-life in size. Is there any historical reason for the same? What does the Catholic Church tell about the reasons for and philosophy behind depicting Infant Jesus with a crown too big for his head?

Comment: If traditional Catholic/Orthodox art **”depicted the Infant Jesus with a crown too big for his head”**, why is the crown on his head and not around his eyes or falling around his neck? This seems like a non-question, unless you can link a particular example to demonstrate your point of view.

Comment: This question appears to be off topic since it asks for art interpretation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin of this custom is Byzantine (Orthodox)

[image]

Up to the advent of Protestantism, Christianity regarded God as the ultimate king. This is also the origin of the old Greek name for a church building: βασιλική (*basilike*, "royal"). In the construction of such a church, the throne & altar would be as far as possible from the door, against the wall (to protect the king from assassination attempts). This and the form & clothing of church ceremonies are taken from the prevailing customs of the Byzantine court. The same goes for the depictions of the Nazarene as a child.

[image]

The best known example of royal children depicted with crowns in Byzantine art is princess [Anna Komnene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Komnene).

Even after the schism between the Catholic and Orthodox churches, the depiction style remains prevalent in Western European art until the advent of Protestantism.